# Current selected tab is not loaded when post back of multi steps form. JavaScript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have simple multi steps form template from W3schools.com. In 2nd tab in step form, clicking the server side button (asp button), then page postback and load 1st tab form (1st step). therefore I tried deafferent ways to load same tab after the postback. That's not successful yet so. I hope your solutions for my code.

Javascript :

```
    <script>
        var currentTabnew;
       var last = sessionStorage.getItem('tab');

        // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
        if (last==0 ||last==null ) {
            currentTabnew = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentTabnew =  last;
        }
showTab(currentTabnew); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
      
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    //sessionStorage.setItem('tab');
    showTab(currentTab);
    
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
        </script>
```

My .aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;


}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
</style>

    <div id="regForm" class="shadow">
  <h3>Registration Form</h3>
<br />
  <div class="tab"><h5>Personal Details</h5> <br />
      <div class="row">
        
<div class="col">
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Full Name"></asp:textbox></div>  
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Surename"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="Date of Birth"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:dropdownlist runat="server"  class="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""  selected hidden>Civil Status</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CV1">Single</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CV2">Married</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CV3">Widowed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CV4">Divorced</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CV5">Separated</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist> </div>
    <div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Land Phone"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="texxt" class="form-control"  placeholder="Address" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="E-mail"></asp:textbox></div>

</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Other Name"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="NIC"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:dropdownlist runat="server"  class="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""  selected hidden>Gender</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="G1">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="G0">Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist> </div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:dropdownlist runat="server"  class="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""  selected hidden>Religion</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R1">Christianity</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R2">Hinduism</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R3">Buddhism</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R4">Islam</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist> </div>
    <div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Mobile"></asp:textbox></div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:dropdownlist runat="server"  class="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""  selected hidden>District</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Jaffna  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Kilinochchi </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Mannar  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Mullaitivu  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Vavuniya    </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Puttalam    </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Kurunegala  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Gampaha </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Colombo </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Kalutara    </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Anuradhapura    </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Polonnaruwa </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Matale  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Kandy   </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Nuwara Eliya    </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Kegalle </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Ratnapura   </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Trincomalee </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Batticaloa  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Ampara  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Badulla </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Monaragala  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Hambantota  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Matara  </asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Value="CV1"> Galle   </asp:ListItem>

    </asp:dropdownlist> </div>
<div class="mb-3"><asp:textbox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Nearest Police Station"></asp:textbox></div>

</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
      <h5>Educational Qualification </h5> <br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3"><asp:dropdownlist runat="server"  class="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value=""  selected hidden>Select Highest Education...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R1">Grade 8</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R2">O/L</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R3">A/L</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R4">Degree</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="R2">Doctor</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R3">PHD</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="R4">Not Mentioned</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:dropdownlist> </div>
    </div>
      <br />
        <h5>Professional Qualification</h5>
      <br />
<div class="row">
    <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover" BorderStyle="None">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Institute">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"   class="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qualification">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  class="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  class="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                 
                 <input id="btnAdd" type="button" style="width:200px;" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable(<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>)"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="sdfsd" />
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
    <asp:button runat="server" text="Button" />
</div>
  </div>
        
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" class="btn btn-secondary">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div></div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy;2021 SLFEA</p>
       <p class="mb-3 text-muted" style="font-size:small;">Designed by Dockyard Total Solutions Pvt Ltd</p></div>
    <script>
        function addRowToTable(containerId) {
            // Get a reference to the table/GridView...
            var tableRef = document.getElementById('<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>');

            // Get the index of the current last row...
            var lastRow = tableRef.rows.length;

            // Add a row (<tr>) to the table/GridView...
            var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(lastRow - 1);

            // Add a cell (<td>) to the row...
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);

            // Create a TextBox...
            var controlRef = document.createElement('input');
            controlRef.type = 'text';
            controlRef.id = containerId + '_TextBox' + lastRow;
            controlRef.name = controlRef.id;
            controlRef.size = 20;

             var controlRef1 = document.createElement('input');
            controlRef.type = 'text';
            controlRef.id = '01' + '_TextBox' + lastRow;
            controlRef.name = controlRef.id;
            controlRef.size = 20;

            var controlRef2 = document.createElement('input');
            controlRef.type = 'text';
            controlRef.id = '02' + '_TextBox' + lastRow;
            controlRef.name = controlRef.id;
            controlRef.size = 20;


            // Add the TextBox to the cell...
            newCell.appendChild(controlRef);
            newCell1.appendChild(controlRef1);
            newCell2.appendChild(controlRef2);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. For not considering my issue.

This is works for me.

```
<script>
    var currentTab;
    var newCurrentTab = sessionStorage.getItem("lastTab");
    if (newCurrentTab == 0 || newCurrentTab == null) {
        currentTab = 0;
    } else {
        currentTab = newCurrentTab;
    }
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == x.length - 1) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n);
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form... :
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            //...the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastTab", currentTab);

        showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x,
            y,
            i,
            valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false:
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i,
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is working on refreshing. If I click previous or next button after refresh it is not working.